# Showing well-definedness of a group operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let p be an odd prime integer, and let $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $1 \leq r < p$. Let G be a cyclic group of order p generated by g, and let K be a cyclic group of order p-1 generated by k. For $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $b \geq 0$, define

$$(g^a, k^b)*(g^c,k^d) = (g^{a+r^bc},k^{b+d})$$

1. Show that if $a,b,c,d,a',b',c',d' \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $b,b' \geq 0$, and $g^a = g^{a'}, k^b = k^{b'}, g^c = g^{c'},k^d = k^{d'}$, then

$$(g^a, k^b)*(g^c,k^d) = (g^{a'}, k^{b'})*(g^{c'},k^{d'})$$

Deduce that $*$ is a binary operation on $G \times K.$

2. Show that $*$ is commutative if and only if r = 1.

For the first question I don't know how to show that $g^{r^bc} = g^{r^{b'}c'}$.

For the second question, I cannot show $*$ commutative implies r = 1.
(I tried finding a specific values that will give me this result, which is a = a, b = 0, c =0, and d =1 and this will give me $g^a = g^{ra}$ and r must be equal to 1 + kp since G is cyclic group of prime order and since r is less than p , k = 0 and hence r =1. Is this correct?

Comment: Your solution for the second one is good. For the first one, note that since $g^c = g^{c'}$, you can rewrite both sides as powers of some common $x$. Now note that to show powers of this $x$ to be equal you need the powers to be congruent mod $p$, and recall what the condition $k^b = k^{b'}$ says about the relationship between $b$ and $b'$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I still don't know how to proceed with your suggestion

Comment: this is my attempt: 
Since $k^b = k^{b'}$ and k is of order $p-1$. $b = (p-1)qb' + b'$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$, assuming $b \geq b'$. 
Let x = c = c'. So $g^{xr^{(p-1)qb'+b'}} = g^{xr^{b'}} \Rightarrow g^{xr^{(p-1)qb'}r^{b'}} = g^{xr^{b'}} \Rightarrow (g^{xr^{b'}})^{r^{(p-1)qb'}} = g^{xb'}$. Now need to prove that $r^{(p-1)qb'} = (r^{qb'})^{p-1}\equiv 1$(mod p). This is true using fermat little theorem. Hence the result.

Comment: Good, except you have some extra $b'$ there for some reason (you just get $b = (p-1)q + b'$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think the b' should be there $k^b = k^{b'}$ does not necessarily mean $b = (p-1)q + b'$. For example, if my element $k^l$ has order p. then $k^l = k^l((k^l)^{mp})$. Hence $ l = l+l(mp)$. That is how i get the extra b'

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I can't convince me that i can take away the b' here. Can you show me a proof that that is true? If so, what is wrong with my reasoning above

Comment: ok actually i know why now hahaha because it is given that k has order p-1 <FACEPALM>